# SQL Server : return min number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a quick remedy to fix an issue with a legacy system while we are building a new version.

**Overview**

A checklist page check the DB for a certain number of entries per user. The page then check that `count` of entries per a reference table which contains the *required* number of entries ("RequiredRows"), based on what type of user is logged in. The page then iterates the user's entries by the `RequiredRows`.

**Issue**

Obviously this fails when the returned number of entries is less than `RequiredRows`.

**Obvious**

I know most of you, just as I did, will say to update the page(s) to not iterate in that manner. Unfortunately, at this moment it is not possible and much more complicated overall without going into details.

**What I Need**

I need a query that can return the same number of records or more based on the `RequiredCount`.

**Here's an example:**

- User1 logs in as public user
- User2 logs in as a private user
- Public users are required to submit 3 entries
- Private users are required to submit 2 entries

**Scenarios**

1. If User1 has 0 entries, the query should return nothing, no rows.
2. If User1 has 1 entry, the query should return 1 row with data, and 2 rows with `NULL`.
3. If User1 has 2 entries, the query should return 2 rows with data, and 1 row with `NULL`.
4. If User1 has 3 entries, the query should return 3 rows with data.
5. If User2 has 0 entries, the query should return nothing, no rows.
6. If User2 has 1 entry, the query should return 1 row with data, and 1 rows with `NULL`.
7. If User2 has 2 entries, the query should return 2 rows with data.
8. If User2 has 3 entries, the query should return 3 rows with data.

**Database structure**

```
Id    User    Type
-------------------
1     User1   1
2     User2   2

Id    UserType    RequiredRows
--------------------------------
1     Public      3
2     Private     2

Id    UserId    Entry
----------------------
1     1         Test
```

**Desired Results**

When querying for the number of entries for *User1* I need the following result.

```
EntryId
--------
1
null
null
```

When querying for *User2*:

```
EntryId
--------
null
null
```

**Considerations**

While this is only a small sample data, the number of required entries varies between 0-50, depending on different user types.

Comment: Use `IF` and `UNION` to get the results you need.

Comment: @Sami thanks. I'm trying to figure that out. not sure how to use `UNION` in my scenario. Any small code you can provide would help. I'll also search in the meantime.

Comment: Is there more than 2 users? or it's only those two?

Comment: @Sami many more, this is just a small sample

Comment: This is a database question.  Refer to (and define) tables (not pages).

Comment: @Paparazzi, not sure what u mean. However, my version of a quick remedy would be a TSQL solution, vs re-writing the pages referencing this process.

Comment: Can you not update the reference table so that everyone has a required rows value of 0?  It seems like all this work is to just pretend they have their required row count anyway.

Comment: @Paparazzi, actually, the page itself is doing some logic: getting the number of `RequiredRows`, and iterating that many times over the `ResultSet` of the number of entries.

Comment: @AaronDietz, not sure I understand, _Public_ users are required to have 2 entries, not 0.

Comment: Actually fix the question.   Break it down to the data issues.

Comment: @Paparazzi sure thing (but i know the type of answers I'll get afterwards) =)

Comment: Can't help you.   I am one high end db guy that moved on.  And I know an easy solution.

Comment: @Paparazzi I updated the question to include my desired result. I hear ya. I wanna tear this down fix the code on the page, but unfortunately, I can only fix this legacy version through TSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a less relational but verbose approach:

```
DECLARE @User TABLE (
Id INT, [User] VARCHAR(255), [UserTypeId] INT
)
INSERT INTO @User
VALUES (1,'User1',1),(2,'User2',1),(3,'User3',2),(4,'User4',1),(5,'User5',2),(6,'User6',3)

DECLARE @UserType TABLE (
Id INT, UserType VARCHAR(20), RequiredRows INT
)
INSERT INTO @UserType
VALUES (1,'Public',3),(2,'Private',2),(3,'Untrusted',50)

DECLARE @Entries TABLE (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), UserId INT,  [Entry] VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @Entries
VALUES (1,'Test'),(2,'Test'),(2,'Test 2'),(3,'Test')
, (5,'MoreTests1'),(5,'Test2'),(5,'Test 3'),(5,'Test 4')
, (6,'SomeTest1'),(6,'SomeTest2'),(6,'SomeTest3'),(6,'SomeTest4'),(6,'SomeTest5')
, (6,'SomeTest6'),(6,'SomeTest7'),(6,'SomeTest8'),(6,'SomeTest9'),(6,'SomeTest10')

DECLARE @UserId INT = 1

DECLARE @RequiredRows INT = (
    SELECT RequiredRows
    FROM @User u
    INNER JOIN @UserType ut
    ON u.UserTypeId = ut.Id
    WHERE u.Id = @UserId)

DECLARE @ExistingRows INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @Entries WHERE UserId = @UserId)
DECLARE @MissingRows INT = (SELECT CASE WHEN @RequiredRows < @ExistingRows OR @ExistingRows = 0 THEN 0 ELSE @RequiredRows - @ExistingRows END)

;WITH fill AS (
    SELECT EmptyId FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL)) gen(EmptyId)
)
    SELECT Id as EntryId
    FROM @Entries WHERE UserId = @UserId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT TOP(@MissingRows) a.EmptyId
    FROM fill a, fill b, fill c
```

Basically it determines the required row, 0 in case no entry exists and the existing rows. The rest is selecting the entries and filling, if necessary with empty tuples.

You can change the `@UserId` to 1 for scenario **2**, `@UserId = 2` for scenario **3**, `@UserId = 3` for scenario **6** and `@UserId = 4` for scenario **1**, but you can easily add data to cover the other test cases.

**Edit:** Added some more test data and rewritten the query to minimize amount of data reads.

**Edit2:**
Here is a compact [recursive cte](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx), that uses [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to enumerate entries and makes sure it has the number of required rows.

```
DECLARE @User TABLE (
Id INT, [User] VARCHAR(255), [UserTypeId] INT
)
INSERT INTO @User
VALUES (1,'User1',1),(2,'User2',1),(3,'User3',2),(4,'User4',1),(5,'User5',2),(6,'User6',3)

DECLARE @UserType TABLE (
Id INT, UserType VARCHAR(20), RequiredRows INT
)
INSERT INTO @UserType
VALUES (1,'Public',3),(2,'Private',2),(3,'Untrusted',50)

DECLARE @Entries TABLE (
    Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), UserId INT,  [Entry] VARCHAR(255)
)
INSERT INTO @Entries
VALUES (1,'Test'),(2,'Test'),(2,'Test 2'),(3,'Test')
, (5,'MoreTests1'),(5,'Test2'),(5,'Test 3'),(5,'Test 4')
, (6,'SomeTest1'),(6,'SomeTest2'),(6,'SomeTest3'),(6,'SomeTest4'),(6,'SomeTest5')
, (6,'SomeTest6'),(6,'SomeTest7'),(6,'SomeTest8'),(6,'SomeTest9'),(6,'SomeTest10')

DECLARE @UserId INT = 1

;WITH rcte AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY e.Id) AS RN
        , e.Id
        , ut.RequiredRows
    FROM @Entries e 
    INNER JOIN @User AS u ON e.UserId = u.Id
    INNER JOIN @UserType AS ut ON u.UserTypeId = ut.Id
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RN + 1, NULL, RequiredRows
    FROM rcte r
    WHERE r.RN + 1 <= RequiredRows
)
SELECT RN, MAX(Id) AS EntryId
FROM rcte 
GROUP BY RN
```

Comment: +1! Thanks! This also works as desired! While this does seem more _legible_ at my current level of "expertise", I still prefer the `CTE` version by @RossBush.

Comment: A beginner will start writing simple yet buggy code. As he advances, he learnes principles, patterns and in depth knowledge of a framework and start overengineering things. It takes some experience to write clean, simple, working and maintainable solutions. The above statement doesn't require to figure what a recursive cte is, what it is used for or how the outer joins generates null values.

Comment: I am not saying Ross solution is bad, frankly I started with recursion as well, but it became complex, handling all scenarios. I admit his query is elegant as such, but it fails some scenarios. Use some more data, at least on my machine his query returns wrong entry Ids for multipe users.

Comment: You are correct! I tested this as well. While for our case, the exact ID is not needed, I would say that @RossBush's solution is not good, unless fixed.

Comment: here is another testcase: http://rextester.com/CZBEF67902 where userId 5 should have 4 entries

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! While this is only a temp/quick fix to plug the hole in the boat, using `CTE` isn't required and I marked urs as the answer. Thanks for catching this!

Comment: Curiously, on the `INNER JOIN @Entries e ON e.UserId = @UserId`, why this way, vs `INNER JOIN @Entries e ON e.UserId = u.Id`

Comment: Another thing, while implementing your solution on real data, the max number of rows i got was 4. Maybe due to my limited sample data in my original question, some user types have 10+ entries required.

Comment: Please try my updated statement, I removed the not needed TOP limitation for the entries. As for the inner join, it was an assumption that the scalar cumputation might be faster, but I would need to look at the query plan.

Comment: That's the one I used, see http://rextester.com/edit/ODE20915, I changed Public to 30 required.

Comment: Another interesting thing, @RossBush's code does work with my real data, but as you proved it does work with this test data. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I assumed there are at most 3 required entries. Is there any limit?

Comment: Currently, the highest limit is 53. But I don't know if new requirements will be added from now till the rewritten version comes to life. I'd hate to hard code a limit. by adding more `UNION ALL SELECT NULL`

Comment: I added a cte with generated null values, this would work using Cartesian product for up to 1000 filled nulls. If you need more, you simply join the cte to increase the amount by 10 times, for each join

Comment: Wow, that's a nice solution. Thanks! Will try it out and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

This could work.

```
DECLARE @User TABLE(UserID INT,UserName NVARCHAR(20), UserTypeID INT)
DECLARE @UserType TABLE(UserTypeID INT, UserTypeName NVARCHAR(50), RequiredEntries INT)
DECLARE @UserEntry TABLE(UserEntryID INT, UserID INT, EntryName NVARCHAR(50))
INSERT @User SELECT 1 , 'User1', 1
INSERT @User SELECT 2 , 'User2', 2
INSERT @UserType SELECT 1, 'Public', 3
INSERT @UserType SELECT 2, 'Private', 2
INSERT @UserEntry SELECT 1,1,'Test'


DECLARE  @UserID INT = 1
;
WITH RequiredEntries AS(
   SELECT UserTypeID, RowNumber=1, RequiredEntries FROM @UserType UT
   UNION ALL
   SELECT UserTypeID,RowNumber=RowNumber + 1,RequiredEntries FROM RequiredEntries IR  WHERE IR.RowNumber < IR.RequiredEntries
),
UserEntries AS(
    SELECT UserID,EntryNumber=COUNT(*)
    FROM @UserEntry UE
    GROUP BY UserID,EntryName
),
UserTotals AS(
    SELECT UserID,TotalEntries=COUNT(*)
    FROM @UserEntry UE
    GROUP BY UserID
)
SELECT 
    EntryNumber
FROM   
    @User U 
    INNER JOIN RequiredEntries RE ON RE.UserTypeID=U.UserTypeID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN UserEntries UE ON UE.UserID=U.UserID AND EntryNumber=RE.RowNumber
    INNER JOIN UserTotals UT ON UT.UserID=U.UserID AND UT.TotalEntries > 0 --1 and 5
WHERE
    U.UserID=@UserID
ORDER BY 
    RE.RowNumber
```

Comment: Wow! I just tried this and it seems to work magnificently! I will test this against my real data.

Comment: You sir, are a GENIUS! I too was trying to use `CTE`'s but I'm not this clever... yet... hopefully!

Comment: Raul Sebastian - Doh!

Comment: To address 1 and 5, I would create another cte grouped by user that sums entries. Then inner join that with the main query and stick a where clause to limit where entrycount>0. I am too tired at the moment.

Comment: Interesting, When I tested i thought I did see #1 and #5 correct. Maybe I'm too tired as well! ;)

Comment: I added the check for 1 and 5, however, I winged it so it may have a typo.